# What is on my drywall and why it smells?

Tags: drywall, smell

One of the small rooms in my recently bought home smells when door is closed for 24 hours or longer. Something must be outgassing. This is the only room in my home that has two different drywall surface (all other rooms have paint and no smell issue).

I am trying to figure what it might be. I put a photo that is showing a part of the room where two walls meet each other with 90 degree angle (L shaped). I suspect that wall with vertical line (undulated part) could be wall paper (you can leave mark with your nail if you press)?; OR some other types of drywall finish? If it's wall paper I am planning to remove it and paint it. I wonder if any expert can recognize what might be on the wall, and where the smell might be coming from.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: only you can determine 100% if it is wallpaper ... try peeling a corner

Comment: Stale cigarette smell?